# @JavaScript is no annotation type

Tags: javascript, java, eclipse, annotations, vaadin

I get this error message in my Java Project. How to resolve? I just build the standard archtype application example of Vaadin. I want to try out including JavaScript into my project. But already the simple annotation gives an error Message: @JavaScript is no annotation type

I tried this: Project->Properties->JavaCompiler->AnnotationProcessing->Enable Still an error. Maybe I have to include certain .jars?

[image]

Here is the code:

```
package my.vaadin.app;

import javax.servlet.annotation.WebServlet;

import com.vaadin.annotations.Theme;
import com.vaadin.annotations.VaadinServletConfiguration;
import com.vaadin.server.VaadinRequest;
import com.vaadin.server.VaadinServlet;
import com.vaadin.ui.Button;
import com.vaadin.ui.Label;
import com.vaadin.ui.TextField;
import com.vaadin.ui.UI;
import com.vaadin.ui.VerticalLayout;

import com.vaadin.annotations.*;



/**
 * This UI is the application entry point. A UI may either represent 
 * a browser window 
 * (or tab) or some part of an HTML page where a Vaadin application 
 * is embedded.
 * <p>
 * The UI is initialized using {@link #init(VaadinRequest)}. This              
 * method is intended to be 
 * overridden to add component to the user interface and initialize 
 * non-component functionality.
 */

@Theme("mytheme")
@JavaScript("javascript-test.js")
public class MyUI extends UI {

    @Override
    protected void init(VaadinRequest vaadinRequest) {
        final VerticalLayout layout = new VerticalLayout();

        final TextField name = new TextField();
        name.setCaption("Type your name here:");

        Button button = new Button("Click Me");
        button.addClickListener(e -> {
            layout.addComponent(new Label("Thanks " + name.getValue() 
                    + ", it works!"));
        });

        layout.addComponents(name, button);

        setContent(layout);
    }

    @WebServlet(urlPatterns = "/*", name = "MyUIServlet", 
    asyncSupported = true)
    @VaadinServletConfiguration(ui = MyUI.class, productionMode =         
    false)
    public static class MyUIServlet extends VaadinServlet {
    }
}
```

Comment: Where do you expect that annotation to come from? Annotations are like classes: you have to `import` them or else share the same package.

Comment: @Pointy Looks like a Vaadin feature, although because the OP is not showing an [mcve] it's only possible to guess that an import is missing.

Comment: Sorry for not showing everything. But I imported com.vaadin.annotations.*; @Pointy: By the way there are two different error symbols in Eclipse. If the import is missing the error symbol would look different.

Comment: @Pointy: Can you please remove the downvote. I added enough information, I think.

Comment: @cryp71x I would but I didn't downvote.

Comment: @user202729 please, I edited the content.

Answer (score 1):

Try importing it with:

```
import com.vaadin.ui.JavaScript;
```

Comment: Sure? I know another Vaadin 8 Project where this works. Also take a look at https://vaadin.com/docs/v8/framework/articles/IntegratingAJavaScriptComponent.html

Comment: Sorry, my bad. The annotation was introduced much before v10. But anyway, I changed the answer to what I think is correct. In Eclipse you can generate the import statement with Ctrl+Space after the name of the class or by using Source” > Organize Imports (or the equivalent keyboard shortcut). Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

Strangely it is indeed a missing import. I changed

```
import com.vaadin.annotations.*;
```

to

```
import com.vaadin.annotations.JavaScript;
```

and it works. I also included

```
<swagger-core-version>1.5.15</swagger-core-version>
```

under properties and

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>io.swagger</groupId>
    <artifactId>swagger-annotations</artifactId>
    <version>${swagger-core-version}</version>
</dependency>
```

into the pom.xml